# Изменение опций контекстного меню браузера

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Если возможно как в браузере(Chrome) в меню, появляющемся после нажатия правой кнопки мыши, добавить свою опцию?
P.s.
С помощью `background` страницы расширения.